# let $x_1, x_2 ,x_3$ be 3 points on the unit circle in the plane. Then there must exist atleast one pair for which $||x_i + x_j||$ $\geq 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, complex-analysis, euclidean-geometry

let $x_1, x_2 ,x_3$ be 3 points on the unit circle in the plane. Then there must exist at least one pair for which $||x_i + x_j||$ $\geq 1$.
I tried doing this but nothing interesting came up
Can anyone give me a hint on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember $||x_i+x_j||^2 = 2+2<x_i, x_j> = 2+2\cos(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is the angle between the unit vectors $x_,x_j$. Thus, if you want $||x_i+x_j||^2\geq 1$, then you want that angle $\alpha$ to be at most $\dfrac{2\pi}{3}.$ Now a basic pigeon-hole principle finishes the problem.